# Subtitle program for DVD on Mac

Tags: macos, dvd, subtitles, real-time

I like the looks of Belle Nuit Subtitler, even though the price is a bit high.

Does anyone know any other program like it that can add subtitles to a video stream while watching the stream itself?

I want this to translate DVD's, in case that matters.

I'm willing to purchase it if the program can deliver what i need but would like to see alternatives to Belle Nuit.

Answer (score 0):

There is a greate online subtitle editor [here](http://subtitle-horse.org/). I'm not sure if that's what you're after. I believe you can download the software and run it on a local machine too.

As for adding the subtitles to a video stream, Quicktime pro can add subtitles from a text file, without rendering, by adding a [text track](http://www.apple.com/quicktime/tutorials/texttracks.html). You can create it with a text editor. This has the advantage that it can be turned on and off - even when the video is embedded in a web page.